# Word Digital Signature

Tags: ms-word, certificate, ms-office, digital-signature

From what I understand PDF is an open format and you can digitally sign the PDF document as proof using a certificate issued by a CA which follows open standards.What about Microsoft word can I sign using an open standards certificate? Can someone clarify if I can do a signature on word using a standard certificate or only from Microsoft.

Comment: I belive the question has not been answered yet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hope it will help:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=79D06E72-4B45-4669-9EAC-0ECA5821E8FF&displaylang=en